# Change a binding to a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, dagger-2

I create a proxy class using a APT(Annotation Processor) to do some instrumentation in the original class.

I want to change a binding in Dagger 2 with this proxy instead of the default implementation when the implementation class is annotated with @MyCustomAnnotation.

Implementation(By user):

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  // Implementation
}
```

Original Module:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  MyService providesService() {
    return new MyServiceImpl();
  }
}
```

Final module replacing the implementation:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  MyService providesService() {
    return new MyServiceImplProxy();
  }
}
```

I need something transparent from a user perspective.

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up using @Binds and doing a double bind.

Changed the user module to a simple @Binds:

```
@Module(includes = { OverrideModule.class })
public abstract class AppModule {
  @Binds
  @Singleton
  abstract MyService providesMyService(MyServiceImpl impl);
}
```

And created a override module:

```
@Module
public abstract class OverrideModule {
  @Binds
 abstract MyServiceImpl providesMyServiceImpl(MyServiceImplProxy impl);
}
```